# how can I find out if a git submodule has new commits

Tags: git, git-submodules

We have quite a few repositories with submodules and we would like to report which submodules are candidates for upgrading because the repository they refer to has new commits. Is there a way to do this without changing the currently checked out version?

basically there are 3 different commits that we would like to know about;
1) the commit to which origin's containing repository is pointing to
2) the commit to which the local containing repository is pointing to (this might be different from 1 because of a manual pull of the submodule
3) the head of the submodule repository.

If local is behind origin we would like to do a submodule update.
If local is ahead origin, we don't want to do a submodule update because it is probably changed by the developer.
If local is behind the head of the submodule repository, we would like to get a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit verbose, but you can use `awk`, `sed`, etc. to prune it down to the pertinent information, but I would start with `git submodule foreach git remote show` or `git submodule foreach git fetch; git submodule foreach git log master..origin/master`. That should provide enough information to build a script to do the automatic updates, etc.