# How can I determine whether a git submodule is actually ahead or behind its remote?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I did find an old question that answers this to some extent, but it's not entirely helpful as it stands:

[how can I find out if a git submodule has new commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529141/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-git-submodule-has-new-commits)

Mostly I was hoping that git has changed since 2012 enough that this is easier.

When I do a `git status` with my current setup I get two types of output. The usual lines

`modified: path/to/submodule (new commits)`

And some extra info about the submodules like this

```
* path/to/submodule/
  < upstream repo
  < added more commits
  < you should update this submodule

* path/to/submodule/
  > These commits
  > don't exist upstream
  > you should commit this submodule
```

Git seems to know exactly what is going on, but I don't seem to have the tool to determine this myself.

My goal is to know for each submodule whether I should commit it, update it, or manually investigate because there's a mix of `>` and `<` in there. I'm about to write a script based on heuristics, which feels bad, so better ideas are gratefully received.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.8.5.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try, from the parent repo:

```
git config status.submodulesummary -1
git status --long
```

That should display any commit of your submodule not yet pushed to the submodule [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309).

Comment: This just gives me the output I've already got. Submodules are listed as (new commits) regardless of whether they're ahead or behind.