How to check for new commits in remote in a submodule without merging them
I want to check if a submodule has new commits.
I want to use gitpython.
Can i use git submodule status? I use: git submodule update -N and other git commands.
The main task is to see if there are new commits in the submodules. Then the user will decide whether to update or not.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12533308/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+have+new+commits
